# With AngularJS can I call a function when a user changes a value in a text field?

Tags: angularjs

I have some text fields on my web page. Is there a way that I can call a function when a user changes a value in a text field without using a watch?

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Check out ng-change. It allows you to run a function when an input changes.

```
<script>
  function Controller($scope) {
    $scope.counter = 0;
    $scope.change = function() {
      $scope.counter++;
    };
  }
</script>
<div ng-controller="Controller">
  <input type="text" ng-model="confirmed" ng-change="change()" id="ng-change-example1" />
  <label for="ng-change-example2">Confirmed</label><br />
  <tt>counter = {{counter}}</tt><br/>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there any way I can put a delay on that so it does not fire for example for 1 second?

Comment: Well, no...kind of. You could put a timeout in your change() function. But there's no way to tell NG to delay it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough mana to make comment, so - for delaying fire action you can use **ng-model-options** directive and **debounce**

Details in documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions